# Best way to add record in reference table if not found

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to implement a simple tag system in my app. When users want to tag an object, they can use existing tags and/or create new tags at the same time. I have a table 'tag' which just stores the unique tag string value as a PK. In 'object_tag' I have a FK reference to this column. In a request from the client there can be multiple tags for one object. On the server I will loop through all the tags and store them in 'object_tag'. If the tag doesn't exist in the 'tag' table, it should be inserted first.

What is the most efficient way to do this? I could just check if the tag exists before each insert, but I want to minimize the database I/O.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334183/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619698/good-way-to-store-tags-in-relational-database-when-there-are-variable-numbers-of

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100017/how-have-tags-been-stored-in-the-stack-overflow-database-design

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging/20871

Answer (score 0):

You will need 3 tables as follows:

Object - list of objects, primary key oid
Tag - list of tags, primary key tid
ObjectTag - pairs of oid, tid values

See also:

[Tags: Database schemas](http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas)

> The Problem: You want to have a database schema where you can tag a
>   bookmark (or a blog post or whatever) with as many tags as you want.
>   Later then, you want to run queries to constrain the bookmarks to a
>   union or intersection of tags. You also want to exclude (say: minus)
>   some tags from the search result.

- "[MySQLicious](http://nanovivid.com/projects/mysqlicious/)" solution - uses one denormalized table. MySQLicious imports del.icio.us data into a table with this structure.
- "Scuttle" solution - Scuttle organizes its data in two tables. That table “scCategories” is the “tag”-table and has got a foreign key to the “bookmark”-table.
- "Toxi Solution" [Toxi](http://toxi.co.uk/) came up with a three-table structure. Via the table “tagmap” the bookmarks and the tags are n-to-m related. Each tag can be used
  together with different bookmarks and vice versa. This DB-schema is
  also used by [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/).

see also [Tagging system: Toxi solution questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506181/tagging-system-toxi-solution-questions)

Comment: Yes, that is how my database looks like. My question is how to insert the object tags into the database efficiently. When I add object tags I don't know if the tag itself exists in the Tag table, so then I would have to check if each tag exists before every insert. Is there any way around this so I don't have to check each time?